# Calculate price javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I'm stuck with calculating the price in javascript. If i like ones the button, it will print the price but after clicking twice it shows the same price. but it needs to be for example: 39 + 39 + 39  = price. but it only shows 39..

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function()
{
     price ();
}

function price()
{
     var type = document.getElementById("tickettype").value;
     var price;

     switch(type)
     {
          case "normal":
          price=39;
          break;

          case "vip":
          price=99;
          break;
     }

     var totaal = price;

     printPrice(totaal);
}

function printPrice(p_totaal)
{
     document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = p_totaal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `total` variable outside the `price()` scope like:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function()
{
     price ();
}
var totaal = 0; // Changed here
function price()
{
     var type = document.getElementById("tickettype").value;
     var price;

     switch(type)
     {
          case "normal":
          price=39;
          break;

          case "vip":
          price=99;
          break;
     }
     totaal += price; // Changed here
     printPrice(totaal);
}

function printPrice(p_totaal)
{
     document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = p_totaal;
}
```

What you did is redefine the variable and don't increase the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a variable outside the scope of a function:

```
var currPrice = 0;
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function()
{
     price ();
}

function price()
{
     var type = document.getElementById("tickettype").value;
     var price;

     switch(type)
     {
          case "normal":
          price=39;
          break;

          case "vip":
          price=99;
          break;
     }
     currPrice = currPrice + price;

     printPrice(currPrice);
}

function printPrice(p_totaal)
{
     document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = p_totaal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. You can also get rid of that `switch` statement and just use a mapping between ticket types and prices:

```
var total = 0;
var ticket_prices = {
    'normal': 39,
    'vip': 99
};

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    var type = document.getElementById('tickettype').value;
    var price = ticket_prices[type];
    total += price;

    document.getElementById('totalprice').innerHTML = total;
}
```